# Disable retained MQTT messages in Rabbit MQ

Tags: rabbitmq, mqtt

For legacy reasons, I need to disable retained messages on an MQTT node running RabbitMQ.

After researching the issue, it appears that the Rabbit MQ team [has indeed added such a feature](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-mqtt/issues/136) in a file called [rabbit_mqtt_retained_msg_store_noop.erl](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-mqtt/blob/master/src/rabbit_mqtt_retained_msg_store_noop.erl).

I am otherwise unfamiliar with the codebase and could not find mention of the noop retainer anywhere in the documentation.

How do I enable `rabbit_mqtt_retained_msg_store_noop`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rabbit_mqtt_retained_msg_store_noop` is enabled by adding thefollowing to configuration:

```
[
  {
    rabbitmq_mqtt, [
      {retained_message_store, rabbit_mqtt_retained_msg_store_noop}
    ]
  }
].
```